# How to get id from a list?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I have a list, i want to select a option from the list and then send the id to a servlet, then insert  the id in database:

This is the jsp where i send the data name,

```
<label class="etiqueta">Costumer:</label>
<% Conexion conex = new Conexion();
    String URL = conex.URL;
    String USERNAME = conex.USERNAME;
    String PASSWORD = conex.PASSWORD;
    Connection conexion = null;
    try {
        Statement sentencia = null;
        ResultSet resultado = null;
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        if (!conexion.isClosed()) {
            sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
            resultado = sentencia.executeQuery("select name,a_Paterno,a_Materno from person where rol='costumer'");
            out.println("<select style='width:300px;border:1px;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;'name='cliente'");
            out.println("<option>Select costumer</option>");
            while (resultado.next()) {
                String name = resultado.getString("name");
                out.println("<option value='" + name + "'>" + name + "</option>");
            }
            out.println("</select>");
            conexion.close();
        } else {
            out.println("fallo");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("error: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

////
    This is the code from my servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    //int idcliente = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("¿¿¿¿id???"));
    String fecha = request.getParameter("fecha");
    String actividad = request.getParameter("actividad");
    double horas = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("horas"));

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<title></title>");
    out.println("Cliente: "+ "\n" +nombreCliente+ " Añadido Correctamente \n"+telefono+ "\n");
    out.println("<a href='main.jsp'>Volver</a>");
    out.println("</html>");

    Consultas con = new Consultas();
    con.insertActividad(fecha, actividad, horas);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the value you want to submit is the value of the option `value='"+id+"'`

```
while(resultado.next())
{
 String name= resultado.getString("name");
 int id= resultado.getInt("id");
 out.println("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");
}
```

On the servlet to get the value of selected option, you do like this:

```
int idcliente = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cliente"));
```

You can set the value = 0 for the empty option to avoid the parse exception

```
out.println("<option value ='0'>Select costumer</option>");
```

Or you test if `request.getParameter("cliente")` is not empty before parse to int.

Answer (score 0):

Your ID is not a number, it's the `name` you're retrieving in your DB query and including as `value` in your combobox. So try this:

// JSP

```
    //.....
    resultado = sentencia.executeQuery("select name,a_Paterno,a_Materno from person where rol='costumer'");
    out.println("<select style='width:300px;border:1px;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;'name='cliente'");
    out.println("<option value=\"NOMBRE_VACIO\">Select costumer</option>");
    while (resultado.next()) {
        String name = resultado.getString("name");
        out.println("<option value='" + name + "'>" + name + "</option>");
        }
    out.println("</select>");
    //.....
```

// Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String nombreCliente = request.getParameter("client"); // Nombre seleccionado en la combobox "client"
    String fecha = request.getParameter("fecha");
    String actividad = request.getParameter("actividad");
    double horas = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("horas"));

    if (!"NOMBRE_VACIO".equals(nombreCliente)) {
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<title></title>");
        out.println("Cliente: "+ "\n" +nombreCliente+ " Añadido Correctamente \n"+telefono+ "\n");
        out.println("<a href='main.jsp'>Volver</a>");
        out.println("</html>");

        Consultas con = new Consultas();
        con.insertActividad(fecha, actividad, horas);
    }
}
```

You have to decide what to do if no name is selected. If I were you, I'd disable the submit button until a valid name is selected.